# Log response body in spring cloud gateway in filterfactory class

Tags: java, spring-boot, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to modify the response body which is currently gzipped text/html format. As first step i want to log it in abstract filter factory class.

So far i have tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741402/how-to-set-request-body-in-gatewayfilter-with-spring-cloud-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71465870/how-to-get-original-response-body-in-spring-cloud-gateway-webflux-post-filter](https://stackoverflow.com) but with no success. The rewrite response itself do not work.

```
@Component
public class ReportingGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ReportingGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportingGatewayFilterFactory.class);

    public ReportingGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }


    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-properties")
    public static class Config {
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            String originalUriString = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
            String rewrittenUriString = originalUriString.replace("/mygateway/central_reporting/public/dashboards", "/public/dashboards");
            URI rewrittenUri = URI.create(rewrittenUriString); 

            ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(rewrittenUri).headers(headers -> headers.remove("Authorization")).build();
            ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest).build();

            return chain.filter(mutatedExchange);

        };
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "but with no success" is not describes your issue